# PHP, sql query to CSV, format rows for totals

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a working script that, when executed, runs the following SQL query which is then written to a CSV. All of this works perfectly.

However, I'd like to adjust the formatting somewhat. It currently writes results by employee and orders by last night. I'd like to have a row at the end of all agent's records that said something like "Agent's Name: Totals" and then sums up the totals of their records.

For example, each row has their name, phone extension, and then several metrics which are either blank or have an 'x', and lastly a number representing time on the phone. So I'd like to total the x's in the appropriate fields, add the duration of time on the phone, and lastly a count of total calls (which would be a count of that employee's records).

I don't know if this should be done in the SQL, in the CSV code block or if there's a better way to store the metrics with PHP and do this programmatically.

I'm a rookie here, normally just relying on queries in MySQL workbench, so any help is much appreciated.

Here's the script:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn2,
"SELECT
      firstn
    , lastn
    , extension
    , Recieved
    , RecievedKnown
    , Outbound
    , outboundKnown
    , Missed
    , MissedKnown
    , CallingNumber
    , CalledNumber
    , starttime
    , endtime
      , duration
    , HOLDTIMESECS
    , TERMINATIONREASONCODE

FROM (
      SELECT
              u.firstn
            , u.lastn
            , c.extension
            , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Recieved
            , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND answered = 1 AND CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS RecievedKnown
            , CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 1 AND LEGTYPE1 = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END  AS Outbound
            , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 1 AND FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO = k.phone_number THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS outboundKnown
            , CASE WHEN Answered = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Missed
            , CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 0 AND CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS MissedKnown
            , a.CALLINGPARTYNO AS CallingNumber
            , a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO AS CalledNumber
            , b.starttime AS starttime
            , b.endtime AS endtime
            , b.duration
            , a.holdtimesecs
            , a.terminationreasoncode
      FROM ambition.session a
      INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
      INNER JOIN ambition.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
      INNER JOIN jackson_id.users u ON c.extension = u.extension
      LEFT JOIN ambition.known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
      WHERE date(b.ts) >= curdate()
      AND LEGTYPE1 <> 12 -- This keeps the report from having blank spaces due to the 12 legtype.
      AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)

      ) x
    ORDER BY lastn") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));



    $userDetails = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        /* Let me take the extension as the key to store its respective counts */
        $extension = $row['extension'];
        /* Now in your while loop do all the calculations for the user */
        if(!isset($userDetails[$extension])){
            /* Since this is the first time for the extension your doin the calculations */
            $userDetails[$extension]['missedCallCounts'] = 1; /* First time count */
        }else{
            $userDetails[$extension]['missedCallCounts'] += 1; /* Sum up the count */
        }
    }

    foreach($userDetails as $userDetail){
/* In the following line dump the respective userdetails to csv which will show summary */
fputcsv($fp, array_values($userDetails));
}
```

And a screenshot of the current CSV results in excel (omitted names/numbers, but you still see the idea):
[image]

So for extension 7312, under the first two rows would be a new row with something like:

```
7312's Totals | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | - | - | - | - | 76 | 0
```

Comment: While looping each and every user for writing to CSV file. Make an array and store the details of user and echo that at the end of the CSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looping into the sql query to output the same to CSV file, at that time keep the records in generic array and dump once the loop gets over.

For Eg:

```
$userDetails = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
    /* Let me take the extension as the key to store its respective counts */
    $extension = $row['extension'];
    /* Now in your while loop do all the calculations for the user */
    if(!isset($userDetails[$extension])){
        /* Since this is the first time for the extension your doin the calculations */
        $userDetails[$extension]['missedCallCounts'] = 1; /* First time count */
    }else{
        $userDetails[$extension]['missedCallCounts'] += 1; /* Sum up the count */
    }
}
```

Now loop into the $userDetails and dump the same to CSV

```
foreach($userDetails as $userDetail){
    /* In the following line dump the respective userdetails to csv which will show summary */
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($userDetails));
}
```

Comment: I will try this shortly, and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work. I've added it into my code between the query and the existing CSV block but it sasys that $row['extension'] is an undefined variable

Comment: @TomN. Please check whats the column name your having for extension. I had assumed extension, but you may have been getting another name or you might have altered the column name

Comment: Yes that is the correct column. However, I have a unique index set on this table for extension and date_of_report, I don't know if that has something to do with it

Comment: I updated my question with the current code I'm using now